# How do I change the way Log4Net rolling file appender creates new names?

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, rollingfileappender

Assuming our current application logs are named AppLog.log, that means that the rolling appender at some point creates AppLog.log.1, AppLog.log.2, etc.  We have a customer that wishes to see AppLog.1.log, AppLog.2.log, etc.  I've been through the documentation and I don't see a way to enforce this, as most people are more interested in inserting dates or other markers into log names rather than moving the indexing around.  Is there a way to move that index value to the interior of a log file name for rolling appender?

Answer (score 0):

If you use log4net 1.2.11 or later then you can use the `PreserveLogFileNameExtension` property.

```
<preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
```